# Failed to send an update Symfony 6 Mercure

Tags: php, docker, symfony6, mercure

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.2.29
    ports:
      - "3307:3306" #outside:inside docker container from within
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
    volumes:
      - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/build/db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    networks:
      - symfony

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/project/:cached
    ports:
      - 8080:80 # Ports that are exposed, you can connect to port 8001 to port 80 of the container.
    links:
      - php
      - mercure
    networks:
      - symfony

  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php
    expose:
      - 2443
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:toor@db/test_db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/project/:cached # Location of the project for php-fpm. Note this should be the same for NGINX.*
      - ./docker/build/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/build/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
    links:
      - mercure
    networks:
      - symfony

      ###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:3000
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ':3000'
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_JWT_SECRET}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_JWT_SECRET}
      # Set the URL of your Symfony project (without trailing slash!) as value of the cors_origins directive
      MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |-
        cors_origins *
        anonymous
    command: /usr/bin/caddy run --config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
    volumes:
      - mercure_data:/data
      - mercure_config:/config
    networks:
      - symfony

volumes:
  mercure_data:
  mercure_config:
  persistent:

networks:
  symfony:
```

## config/packages/mercure.yaml

```
mercure:
  hubs:
    default:
      url: '%env(MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL)%'
      jwt:
        secret: '%env(MERCURE_JWT_SECRET)%'
        publish: [ '*' ]
```

I have this configuration for my symfony application. The Mercure hub is running fine on localhost:8081. If I send an update over the UI of the hub, my javascript client can receive the update.

The problem is I can not publish an update with `HubInterface` like this.

```
$update = new Update('https://example.com/my-private-topic', json_encode($message));

$hub->publish($update);
```

This said: failed to send an update and nothing more.

I tried to use another JWT according to documentation of symfony 6.3.

// Publisher's JWT must contain this topic, a URI template it matches or * in mercure.publish or you'll get a 401
// Subscriber's JWT must contain this topic, a URI template it matches or * in mercure.subscribe to receive the update

But obvisiously it did not help.

I tried to configure in yaml file like this but nothing happend

```
framework:
      http_client:
        default_options:
            verify_peer: false
```

Comment: Try opening http://example.com:8081/.well-known/mercure. It should say: Missing "topic" parameter. If it does, that need to be your MERCURE_URL and MERCURE_PUBLILC_URL